# knockout issue with checkbox and checked and change bindings

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, binding, onchange, checked

I just discovered a problem with knockout (3.0 and 3.1) and checkboxes

The problem is, change event binding for a checkbox does not occur consistently across different browsers.

See the code below

```
<table >
  <tr> 
    <td >
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: CheckVal, event: { change: refresh }' />
    </td>
    <td>Check Value in checked binding: <span data-bind="text: CheckVal"></span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
    <td>Check Value in changed event binding: <span data-bind="text: CheckValChanged"></span> 
    </td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

And the javascript

```
function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.CheckVal = ko.observable(true);
    this.CheckValChanged = ko.observable(true);

    this.refresh = function() {
        self.CheckValChanged(self.CheckVal());
    }
}

viewModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

In Firefox, change event binding occurs AFTER the checkbox value was changed, so in change event handler we can read the actual value of the checkbox (that is, if checkbox is checked, the bound field has value = *true*).

In all other browsers (and I tested with Chrome, IE 11, Opera and Safari), the change event binding seems to occur BEFORE actually changing the value of the bound field (that is, of checkbox is checked, the value read in change handler is false, and if unchecked, the value read is true)

You can see the issue demonstrated at http://jsfiddle.net/bzamfir/su6SW/2/

The problem is not only the fact that the behavior is inconsistent across the browsers, but also that for most browsers it seems counter-intuitive: the event is *change*, not *changing* or *beforechange*. It looks natural to me that it should fire when change is completed, so the bound value should reflect the current checked state, not the previous one.

My problem here, beside the issue itself, is to find a workaround to handle this consistently. My problem is, I need to populate a drop-down based on the value of checkbox, and I choose to do it in change event (which now seems to be a bad choice, giving the issue found).

I think the way to go is to use a computed observable, which I hope should work as expected.

I'm waiting for both confirmation of the bug, and also for suggestions to best handle this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is make use of a knockout subscription to the CheckVal observable, instead of using the change javascript event.

The subscribe event is then fired every time the CheckVal observable changes.

Your MainViewModel would look something like this:

```
function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.CheckVal = ko.observable(true);
    this.CheckValChanged = ko.observable(true);

    this.CheckVal.subscribe(function(value) { 
        self.CheckValChanged(value);
    });
}
```

and your  tag can then change to:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: CheckVal' />
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I need to populate a drop-down based on checkbox's value, which I need to do in checkbpx's change event. If I keep change event, it still has the inconsistent and wrong value across browsers. See http://jsfiddle.net/bzamfir/su6SW/7/

Comment: Why do you need the change event? Why can't you populate the dropdown in the `CheckVal` subscription, because then you are not browser dependent anymore.

Comment: That should work, but it is actually a "hack", which I might be hard to understand later, and will give a hard time to another developer which might try to understand it later. I would prefer a more "standard" approach. But thanks for suggestion anyway :)

Comment: Personally i think its more confusing using a mixture of knockout and javascript events like this. If you use a subscribe you can be 100% sure that the CheckVal value is the most recent one. With using a mixture of knockout observables and javascript events you cannot be sure of the order of events based on different browser's implementations.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I used the change event extensively in several applications, to update dependent controls (especially when data in some controls needed to be retrieved from server, depending on other controls's values), and never had any problem so far.

Comment: You shouldn't use jquery events with knockout, it is an anti-pattern. I would not want to be the one picking up after you.

Comment: I agree with @djbieljeski, its not great practice to mix methodologies. However if you wanted to keep it as it is you could try setting a timeout in your refresh function to a few milliseconds to allow the observable to update before setting your CheckValChanged() observable.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why you think I'm using jquery with knockout, because I'm not. What I actually used to do was: 1.bind the ui control to model's observable e.g. dropdown States to State observable); 2. bind change event to a function in model - e.g. stateChanged(). 3. in stateChanged, use value of State observable in ajax call, to load cities from the state, which then I assign to Cities observableArray. Please clarify what is wrong with this pattern?

Comment: Does your question itself not detail what is wrong with this pattern? Using a mixture of jquery events and knockout removes some aspect of control from you and you are then more at the mercy of the browser (which no one likes!). I'm sure usually it works perfectly fine, but its just when you find cases like this that it is hard to find a workaround